# No Signal on display connected to Thunderbolt dock

Tags: linux

I have a desktop PC that I recently upgraded. I'm using Arch Linux that is up to date. It contains an ASRock X570M Pro4 mainboard, AMD Ryzen 9 5900X, and ASRock Thunderbolt 3 AIC R2.0 for the Thunderbolt port and an AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT.
Previously I had an AMD Ryzen 5 and an AMD Radeon RX 570.

Before the upgrade I had the PC connected via Thunderbolt to my Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock, and my two monitors connected via DisplayPort to the docking station and everything worked fine.

I now had to connect one of the displays directly via HDMI, because if they are connected via Thunderbolt, they claim to receive no signal, once the display manager starts.

When I boot, both displays work, I can use both to go into the BIOS setup. The output of the init process is also show on both monitors (probably because early KMS is not enabled?) so it generally works with Linux. Once the display manager starts (GDM in my case) the display connected via the Thunderbolt dock shows "No Signal" and turns of. It is still shown as connected in the display setting and by xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.78    72.04    60.00    50.01    48.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   1920x1200     59.95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   1600x1200     59.95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1680x1050     59.88                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   1440x900      59.90                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1280x800      59.95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1152x864      75.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   832x624       74.55                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   720x576       50.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   720x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   720x400       70.08                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
DisplayPort-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
DisplayPort-5 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.78                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   1920x1200     59.88                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   1680x1050     59.95                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1280x1024     75.02    69.95    60.02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   1440x900      59.89                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1152x864      75.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   832x624       74.55                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   720x576       50.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   720x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   720x400       70.08                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
DisplayPort-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I disconnect it and reconnect it I get some errors from the amdgpu drive, not sure this is related:

```
Jun 11 12:35:19 maufl-tower kernel: [drm] DM_MST: starting TM on aconnector: 00000000b121fac1 [id: 105]  
Jun 11 12:35:19 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:19 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:19 maufl-tower kernel: [drm] Downstream port present 1, type 0  
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed                                                                                                                                                                                
Jun 11 12:35:25 maufl-tower kernel: amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: [drm] *ERROR* mstb 00000000be519c78 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
```

I tried different Thunderbolt security settings in the BIOS and Gnome Xorg and Gnome Wayland. I tried disconnecting the display power and reconnecting it. I tried connecting the displays to the Thunderbolt dock using HDMI. I waited for kernel 5.18.

I assume it's a problem with the graphics driver. How could I continue to debug this?

Comment: Also having this but with a 6500XT. It's  completely new setup so I can't really compare. Fedora 36. Output directly via DP or HDMI works perfectly.

Comment: @user1259201: same here, with Arch Linux as in OP, but on 2 Dell laptops of type XPS15 9560.

Comment: Same problem here. Thinkpad T14 gen3 on 40AN dock. when starting up, I have the image on the two external DP monitors. But after undocking and docking again while the laptop is running, I only see something on the notebook monitor. And in the display settings, all three monitors are overlapping. But even rearranging or disabling/reenabling doesn't really brings back a signal to the external monitors